# Hiding particular divs on selecting dropdown values in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

Selecting dropdown value unable to hide particular divs.Hereis my code.

View:

```js
function showRequiredOption(cval)
 {
  if(cval=='interstate')
  {
   $('#cgst').hide();
   $('#sgst').hide();
   
  }
  else if(cval=='exemptedsales')
  {
   $('#cgst').hide();
   $('#sgst').hide();
   $('#igst').hide();
   
  }
  else
  {
   $('#igst').hide();
   $('#cgst').show();
   $('#sgst').show();
   
  }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-2">
 <div id="legend">
  <legend class="">Profile Information</legend>
 </div>  
    <form role= action="<?php echo site_url();?>invoice/addinvoice" method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="location" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">  
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="user">User</label> 
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
    <select id="user" name="user" onchange="showRequiredOption(this.value);">
     <option value="employee">Local Sales</option>
     <option value="interstate">Inter state</option>
     <option value="freelancer">Stock transfers</option>
     <option value="exemptedsales">Exempted Sales</option>
     <option value="company">Zero Rated Sales</option>
     <option value="freelancer">Job Work</option>
    </select>
   </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="hsn">Freight Charges</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="hsn" placeholder="Enter HSN Number"  >
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group" id="igst">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="hsn">IGST 18%</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="hsn" placeholder="Enter HSN Number"  >
    </div>
  </div> 
   <div class="form-group" id="sgst">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="hsn">SGST 9%</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sgst" placeholder="Enter HSN Number"  >
    </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="form-group" id="cgst">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="hsn">CGST 9%</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cgst" placeholder="Enter HSN Number"  >
    </div>
  </div>   
      <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn" name="submit">Submit</button>
     </form>
    </div>
```

Here if i select interstate,Stock Transfers in dropdown cgst,sgst should be hided and igst should be displayed.

If i select Exempted sales,Zero Rated sales,Job Work in dropdown IGST,CGST,SGST should be hided.

By default It should show sgst and cgst

Comment: @AndrewLi: nice to know, but there was little-to-no PHP code in that snippet, certainly not enough for the snippet to break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply the space between `else if`

Conditions:
   select `interstat or Stock Transfers`  cgst,sgst should be hided and igst should be displayed.

select `Exempted sales,Zero Rated sales,Job Work` in dropdown IGST,CGST,SGST should be hided.

```js
function showRequiredOption(cval)
{
 if((cval=='interstate') || (cval == "stocktransfers"))
 {
  $('#cgst').hide();
  $('#sgst').hide();
  $('#igst').show();
 }
 else if ((cval=='exemptedsales') || (cval=="zeroratedsales") ||(cval=="jobwork"))
 {
  $('#cgst').hide();
  $('#sgst').hide();
  $('#igst').hide();
  
 }
 else
 {
  $('#igst').hide();
  $('#cgst').show();
  $('#sgst').show();
  
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-2">
<div id="legend">
    <legend class="">Profile Information</legend>
</div>  
<form role="form" action="<?php echo site_url();?>invoice/addinvoice" method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="location" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">     
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="user">User</label> 
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
            <select id="user" name="user" onchange="showRequiredOption(this.value)">
                <option value="employee">Local Sales</option>
                <option value="interstate">Inter state</option>
                <option value="stocktransfers">Stock transfers</option>
                <option value="exemptedsales">Exempted Sales</option>
                <option value="zeroratedcompany">Zero Rated Sales</option>
                <option value="jobwork">Job Work</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>      
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="hsn">Freight Charges</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="hsn" placeholder="Enter HSN Number"  >
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="igst" style="display:none;">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="hsn">IGST 18%</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="hsn" placeholder="Enter HSN Number"  >
      </div>
    </div>  
     <div class="form-group" id="sgst">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="hsn">SGST 9%</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sgst" placeholder="Enter HSN Number"  >
      </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="form-group" id="cgst">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="hsn">CGST 9%</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cgst" placeholder="Enter HSN Number"  >
      </div>
    </div>          
  <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn" name="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `cval = "freelancer"`  --->  `cval == "freelancer"`

Comment: getting one issue by default its showing igst it should not show

Comment: which one is the default `local sales`?

Comment: igst should not be displayed only cgst and sgst should be shown

Comment: See updated answer.i was applied with switch statement .Its more better with if satement

Comment: it is also getting same while loading the page it will be local sales only and it is displaying igst and sgst and cgst as well.But if i change anything in dropdown and selecting local sales then igst is hiding but when we load the page at htat time it is not working

Comment: by default whenever we load the page igst should be hided.

Comment: @user7047368 see the updated answer . I was correct .At the time refresh .Its hide the `igst`.Its only show after click

Answer (score 2):

This is just a simple example on how you can achieve that. Hope you'll find the answer through this.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.input').hide();
    $('#sample').change(function(){
        $('.input').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="dropdown" id="sample">
  <option value="cgst">CGST</option>
  <option value="sgt">SGT</option>
</select>

<br />

<hr>

<input id="cgst" type="text" class="input" placeholder="CGST">
<input id="sgt" type="text" class="input" placeholder="SGT">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
function showRequiredOption(cval)
{
    alert(cval);
    if(cval=='interstate')
    {
        $('#cgst').hide();
        $('#sgst').hide();
        $('#igst').show();
    }
    else if(cval=='exemptedsales')
    {
        $('#cgst').hide();
        $('#sgst').hide();
        $('#igst').hide();

    }
    else
    {
        $('#igst').hide();
        $('#cgst').show();
        $('#sgst').show();

    }
}
</script>
```

you forgot add link of jquery js file "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js". so it not worked. use this code it's working